# While pasting data into an Outlook mail body - I get error 4506 "application locked for editing "

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I have to compose a mail body that contains text from multiple sources .

However the line editor.Application.Selection.Paste gives an error "4505" application locked while editing

I paste multiple times from 3 sources to create many mails

```
Dim Outapp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim wd, cmmtrs, ftnt As Object
Dim editor As Object
Dim savePath As String
Dim filePath As String

Dim lastRow As Integer: lastRow = Sheet2.Range("D20000").End(xlUp).Row
filePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
savePath = filePath & "\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set cmmtrs = wd.Documents.Open(savePath & "\ABC.docx", ReadOnly:=True)

'create multiple emails 
For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set Outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = Outapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set vInspector = OutMail.GetInspector
    Set editor = vInspector.WordEditor


    With OutMail
        .To = Sheet2.Range("B" & i).Value
        .CC = Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value
        .Subject = Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value
        .Body = Sheet2.Range("E" & i).Value & vbCrLf & vbNewLine
        Dim lst As Integer: lst = Sheet3.Cells(1000, Sheet3.Range("A3:XAA3").Find(i - 1).Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim col1, col2 As Integer: col1 = Sheet3.Range("A3:XAA3").Find(i - 1).Column
        .Display
    End With

    With OutMail
      If Sheet3.Range("A3:XAA3").Find(i) Is Nothing Then
            col2 = Sheet3.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Sheet3.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
        Else
            col2 = Sheet3.Range("A3:XAA3").Find(i).Column - 1
        End If
        Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(4, col1), Sheet3.Cells(lst + 1, col2)).Copy
        editor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
        editor.Application.Selection.End = editor.Application.Selection.Start
        Application.Wait (Now + 0.0001)

        editor.Application.Selection.Paste
    End With

    If Sheet2.Range("G" & i) = "Yes" Then
        cmmtrs.Content.Copy
        With OutMail
            editor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
            editor.Application.Selection.End = editor.Application.Selection.Start
            Application.Wait (Now + 0.00005)
            editor.Application.Selection.Paste
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: A basi cversion of the above code works for me... No errors... Which line is giving you the error? the first one or the second one?

Comment: editor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body) -- the first one